# Adafruit Motor Shield steppers not turning

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, adafruit, stepper

The Adafruit Motor Shield is connected to 2 steppers which are wired correctly and work when I just use the onestep function. I understand that I cannot drive both at once, so I am using a while loop with two if statements. The Motors were wired:

The left motor was wired:

Green -> m3+
White -> m3-
Red -> m4+
Blue -> m4-

The right motor was wired:

Red -> M2+
Blue -> M2-
Green -> M1+
Black -> M1-

Here is the code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#include "utility/Adafruit_MS_PWMServoDriver.h"

Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield();
Adafruit_StepperMotor *leftMotor = AFMS.getStepper(200, 2);
Adafruit_StepperMotor *rightMotor = AFMS.getStepper(200, 1);
//79 steps per half inch
//half inch is a coordinate
//declaring global variables for Hypotenuses (cord lengths)
int leftHyp;
int rightHyp;
int prevX = 0;
int prevY = 0;
//space from shaft to shaft is 30"
//calculating function
void CordCalc(int xCord, int yCord)
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
  //cords start at 0,0
    xCord = xCord - prevX;
    yCord = yCord - prevY;
    int xSquared = sq(xCord);
    int ySquared = sq(yCord);
    int addSquares = xSquared + ySquared;
    int leftHyp = sqrt(addSquares);
  //now for the right
    int rightX = 60 - xCord;
    int rightXsq = sq(rightX);
    int rightSquares = rightXsq + ySquared;
    int rightHyp = sqrt(rightSquares);
  //leftMotor->step(leftHyp * 79, FORWARD, MICROSTEP);
  //rightMotor->step(rightHyp * 79, FORWARD, MICROSTEP);
    int lStepsTaken = 0;
    int rStepsTaken = 0;
    leftHyp = leftHyp * 79;
    rightHyp = rightHyp * 79;
    bool stepsComplete = false;

  //This is the section for moving the Motors
    while(stepsComplete == false) {
        if(lStepsTaken <= leftHyp) {
            leftMotor->onestep(FORWARD,DOUBLE);
            lStepsTaken++;
            Serial.print("Left");
        }

        if(rStepsTaken < rightHyp) {
            rightMotor->onestep(FORWARD,DOUBLE);
            rStepsTaken++;
            Serial.print("Right!");
        }

        if(rStepsTaken >= leftHyp && lStepsTaken >= leftHyp) {
            stepsComplete = true;
        }
    }

    int prevY = yCord;
    int prevX = xCord;
    stepsComplete = false;
}

void setup()
{
// direction from project point of view
    int leftLength = 0;
    int rightLength = 0;
    leftMotor->setSpeed(122);
    rightMotor->setSpeed(122);
    Serial.begin(9600);

    CordCalc(15, 15);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Loop is empty on purpose because only need to move to coordinates once.

Comment: What is the problem? What your `loop()` is empty? Edit your question and add your schematic.

Comment: you really need to format your code properly. ... correct indentation helps a lot when debugging code

Comment: @jsotola. Solved that for you. Ho, my eyes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing line was afms.begin(); which starts communication with the adafruit motor shield.

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer to close the question.